# I'm new to programming and I get an error CS7036

Tags: c#

I'm getting this error:

> Error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'health' of 'Wizard.Wizard (string, float)

**Player.cs**:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Player {
    private float health = 100f;    
    private string name = "Default";
    private float power = 100f;
    
    public Player() { }
     
    public Player(string name, float health) {    
        this.name = name;
        this.health = health;
    }

    public float Health {    
        get {return health;}    
        set { health = value; }   
    }

    public string Name {
        get { return name;}    
        set { name = value;}    
    }
    
    public virtual void Attack() {
        Debug.Log("The Player is attacking");
    }

//    public void SetHealth(float health) {
//       this.health = health;
//
//   }
//
//    public float GetHealth() {    
//        return this.health;    
//    }

    public void PlayerInfo() {    
        Debug.Log("Player Name Is: " + name + " And Players Health Is: " + health);    
    }
}
```

**Tester.cs**:

```
public class Tester : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start () {
        Player p = new Player();
        Wizard w = new Wizard ("Wizard, 34.123f");
        w.PlayerInfo ();
//         w.name = "Wizard";
//        w.Health = 13.5f;
//         print("\n");
//         w.PlayerInfo ();
//       w.ReplenishMana (33f);
    }
}
```

**Wizard.cs**:

```
public class Wizard : Player {
    private float mana = 33f;

    public Wizard() { }

    public Wizard(string name, float health) {    
        this.Name = name;    
        this.Health = health;    
    }

    public void ReplenishMana(float mana) {
        this.mana = mana;
    }
}
```

I'm new to programming. I can't figure out the issue..

Comment: You're calling it like this: `new Wizard ("Wizard, 34.123f")` but it should be like this: `new Wizard ("Wizard", 34.123f)`, notice that I ended the string after Wizard, so that `34.123f` becomes a second parameter instead of part of the string.

Comment: Basically the error message is saying that you're not passing in the health, as the entire sequence of text there was passed as the name.

Comment: Very basic question like this are not allowed in StackOverflow ask them on [asp.net forumns](https://forums.asp.net/).

Comment: You also should also probably pass the name and health to the base class constructor, then you don't have to set the Name and Health properties yourself: `public Wizard(string name, float health) : base(name, health) { }`

Comment: As a general note, when pasting code please remove all unnecessary lines & spaces.  It took me ages to edit this, especially it was also edited by others before I could finish, so it took me 4 attempts!  Also don't include unnecessary code such as using statements, comment out code etc.

Comment: @LopDev is my answer not useful? It's exact same as other and I had posted it first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your required parameter is Wizard(string, float) , so you need a `string` and a `float` for parameters , so you have to write your code like this:

```
new Wizard ("Wizard", 34.123f)
```

and your problem will be solved.

When you pass parameters you have to pass them in the format that it is required.

This is why you had the error.

Answer (score 0):

It should be  `new Wizard ("Wizard", 34.123f)`. In your code
`new Wizard ("Wizard, 34.123f")` is being treated as you have passed only string to the method.

One suggestion here for you, please try to format your code properly and use the proper naming convention.